# Visual Studio Code and pipenv : "pipenv shell" instead of "source"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I am using a remote SSH on VSCode, on the remote Linux server I have python3.6 and I created some pipenv environments

After a while I understood how to have both the linter (pylint) and the interpreter working on the pipenv environment.

In case someone needs, all what is required is to open directly the destination folder in a new workspace.

What I have problems with is that after opening the workspace, the interpreter is selected with the "source" command and not "pipenv shell" and this makes the variables stored in the .env local file to not be called.

> To overcome this I have then to run manually "pipenv shell" and pipenv
> identifies an already existing and active environment and loads only
> the variables from the .env file

As you can see it can work but is messy on the last part, is there a way to force VScode to run the proper "pipenv shell" rather than "source"?

Comment: These commands do very different things. `pipenv shell` starts a _new_ shell, whereas `source`ing an `activate` script reconfigures your _existing_ shell to use the virtualenv. I'll leave this question for someone who knows VSCode to answer, but it wouldn't astonish me if the way VSCode interacts with a child process across SSH assumed that that actual shell (and not a child it starts!) would be used for command execution.

Comment: To give you an example: You can do `ssh somehost '. foo/bin/activate; myscript'`, but you **can't** do `ssh somehost 'cd foo || exit; pipenv shell; myscript'` -- the `myscript` command won't be reached until the new shell started by `pipenv shell` exits.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12020) regarding python interpreters.